# UIButton Action кнопка Лайк, при нажатии выходит (Int)0?

Tags: swift, parse.com, action, uibutton

Ребята при нажатии кнопка выдает ошибку (Int)0, почему?Я же указал при клике +1 .Кто нибудь может помочь?Я на подобии на примере разбирал и все работало.Заранее спасибо!!!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {





    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    var detailSoccer: Soccer!

    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "CustomSoccerHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)


        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 280
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.reloadData()
        loadMatchSoccer()



        //Headerc

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 280
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView") as! CustomSoccerHeaderView

        header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 280)


        header.nameHeader.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS
        header.countBravo.text = "\(detailSoccer.bravissimo)"


        header.bravoBtn.addTarget(CustomSoccerHeaderView(), action: #selector(CustomSoccerHeaderView.likeBtn(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


        detailSoccer.imagePrS.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
            header.imageHeader.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
        }


        return header
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell") as! SoccerTableViewCell

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Аналитика и обзор матча:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.textSoccer
        case 1:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.detailPrognozS
        default:
            break
        }



        return soccerCell


    }






    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }





    func loadMatchSoccer() {

        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
        query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.matchS)

        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.selectedSoccer = objects!

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
}



import UIKit

class CustomSoccerHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {



    var clickBravisso: Soccer?

    @IBOutlet weak var bravoBtn: UIButton!{
        didSet {
            bravoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = bravoBtn.frame.size.width/2
            bravoBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var countBravo: UILabel!

    @IBAction func likeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if var clikBravo = clickBravisso?.bravissimo {
            print("clikBravo")
            clikBravo += 1
            clickBravisso!.setObject(clikBravo, forKey: "bravissimo")
            clickBravisso!.saveInBackground()
            countBravo.text = "\(clikBravo)"
        } else {
            fatalError("clikBravo is null")


        }

    }



    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeader: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeader: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


    }


    }


Не знаю как правильно обозвать, вот моя инцилизация:


import Foundation
import Parse


class Soccer : PFObject,PFSubclassing {



    @NSManaged var matchS: String

    @NSManaged var imagePrS: PFFile
    @NSManaged var following: Int
    @NSManaged var bravissimo: Int


     @NSManaged var textSoccer : String



    @NSManaged var detailPrognozS: String

    @NSManaged var detailTitleS: String


     class func parseClassName() -> String {

        return "soccer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Один из вариантов, избавьтесь от `forced unwrapping`.

Comment: та пробовал несколько методов! все равно ноль выдает.Может такое что ошибка в headere находиться?Хотя я проверял просто на работу все указал верно, и кнопка работает.ПИсал принт и текст выдает.Подскажите какой нибудь вариант ?

Comment: Где именно выдает 0? Уверены, что попадает в тело if'a?

Comment: падает и показывает в объекте "clickBravo"

Comment: попробуйте if var clikBravo = clickBravisso?.bravissimo {
 print("clikBravo")
} else {
 fatalError("clikBravo is null")
} и посмотрите если ли у вас значение в данный момент

Comment: выдал fatalerror

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76202/discussion-between-shuriktennisist-and-vitali-eller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы при инициализации header, не задаете значения для `clickBravisso`. Необходимо задать значения `header.clickBravisso = detailSoccer`